# Example of a Sufficient MUD-Style and working Text Parser for Python

Tags: python, algorithm, parsing, text

I am in the middle of programming a MUD like game, more for the experience and practice. I am trying to find an algorithm that will effectively prase text commands. If you have played MUD type games before you know what I am talking about. If not and example would be if I typed in the command: 'search' it would execute the 'search' whether you type in s, se, sea, sear, searc, search, etc...

Now I do have a algorithm already established, but the more I think about it the more problems see to arise. In code it goeslike this:

```
 def text_parser(string, command):
    string_list = []
    command_list = []

    for x in string:
        string_list.append(x)

    for x in command:
        command_list.append(x)

    if len(string_list) == 0:     # checks to see if user have entered anything
        return False

    if ((string_list > command_list) - (string_list < command_list)) is 1:    # returns false if string has more items than command
        return False

    else:
        if string_list[:len(string_list)] == command_list[:len(string_list)]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

And you can call this function by:

```
if text_parser('hel', 'hello') is True:
    print('This returns True')

if text_parser('hel', 'Foo') is True:
    print('This returns False')
```

Now this code works perfectly.. exactly what I need for it to do. If I type in 'se' and its other end-members for the command' search' it will always be true... but now comes my biggest problem.. Say i have two commands:

'quit' and 'quaff' and the user only inputs 'qu'

According to my algorithm it will execute both the 'quit' and the 'quaff', because my code is set up as:

```
if (text parser check):
    blah
if (text parser check):
    blach
etc....   # The only way out of this is to do nested if's and elif's.. which will look messy..
```

Which is not what I want to do at all. As you can see many more problems can arise the more commands you set up with the game.

What will be a good algorithm set up for text parsing? Or do I just need to change a few things in my already existing code to address the bugs that can pop up with this set up...? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach can be simplified by having a list of all available commands. And then define a function that will parse your input string and look for a command match like this:

```
all_commands = ['search', 'quit', 'quaff']

def find_command(string, allowed_commands=None):
    if allowed_commands is None:
        # if there is no restrictions, look for all commands
        allowed_commands = all_commands

    matching_commands = []

    for command in commands:
        if command.startswith(string):
            matching_commands.append(command)

    if len(matching_commands) == 1:
        # found a match
        return matching_commands[0]

    # found either no match or more than one
    return None
```

Now, the function `find_command` will find matches for the input `string` and it will either match all commands (`all_commands`) or a given subset (`allowed_commands`), in case you only want to allow certain commands in that situation.

For example:

```
print find_command('se') # returns search
print find_command('search') # returns search
print find_command('qu') # returns None
print find_command('quaf') # returns quaff
print find_command('qu', ['search', 'quit']) # returns quit
```

Comment: I think I like the way you and @MeetTitan approach this. By filtering the user input into a sub-list of available choices, and from there I could execute one of them. Instead of a if statement after another, I could just return the most 'proper' choice and carry that on to my command handler. Alright thank you guys. This made me think of it in a different light.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try pyparsing? It looks good for such tasks. Check examples: http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Examples

Comment: Example of adventure game with pyparsing: http://www.ptmcg.com/geo/python/confs/pyCon2006_pres2.html

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider the [cmd](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html) module, which lets you define commands as methods on a class. It then provides a prompt where you can type the commands and see the results. The parsing is fairly rudimentary, but probably sufficient for you to get started.

cmd was featured on [Python Module of the Week](http://pymotw.com/2/cmd/) a while ago, and it has a very nice tutorial. Here's just a very brief taste:

```
import cmd

class HelloWorld(cmd.Cmd):
    """Simple command processor example."""

    def do_greet(self, person):
        """greet [person]
        Greet the named person"""
        if person:
            print "hi,", person
        else:
            print 'hi'

    def do_EOF(self, line):
        return True

    def postloop(self):
        print

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HelloWorld().cmdloop()
```

When you run the above code you'll get a prompt where you can type commands. For example:

```
(Cmd) greet
hi
(Cmd) greet bob
hi, bob
(Cmd)
```

The module provides the command loop, and it also supports autocompletion, live help, a customizable prompt, and several other features.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, put your commands in a list, and do

```
def parse(userInput):
    returnList = []
    for cmd in commandList:
        if userInput in cmd:
          cmdList.append(cmd)
    return returnList
```

Then you have matching commands in your returned list.